# javascript create json object with blank value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have javascript date array

```
["2015-09-10", "2015-09-16"]
```

I want json object in following format

```
{
"2015-09-10": {},
"2015-09-16": {}
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = {};
var arr  = ["2015-09-10", "2015-09-16"] ;
$.each(arr,function(index,item)
{
     json[item] = {};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = JSON.stringify(["2015-09-10", "2015-09-16"].reduce(function(result, datum) {
    result[datum] = {};
    return result;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateArray = ["2015-09-10", "2015-09-16"];
var dateObj = {};
for(var i=0; i<dateArray.length; i++){
    dateObj[dateArray[i]]={};
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(dateObj));
```